# How to return newly added terms when using wp_set_object_terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I am using wp_set_object_terms to add terms (attributes) to our WooCommerce products:

```
wp_set_object_terms($id, array($migrate_case), 'pa_case');
```

This gives us the advantage (instead of using wp_set_post_terms) that non-existing terms are created automatically.

Is there any way to get wp_set_object_terms() to tell me if it had to create a new term?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you look at this line in the source code: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2407. It is passed an array of old taxonomy term ids, so I assume you could compare with `count()`, maybe.

Comment: @Michael - looks promising: do_action( 'set_object_terms', $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids ); return $tt_ids; How do I get wp_set_object_terms($id, array($migrate_dial), 'pa_dial'); to return the $old_tt_ids?

Comment: You can't, but you can add a filter to the mentioned hook right before your function call to `wp_set_object_terms`, and remove it right afterwards. At least that's what I usually do in similar situations. [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter for a specific function call like so:

```
add_filter( 'set_object_terms', 'checkNewTerm', 10, 6 );

function checkNewTerm( $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids ) {

    // Do stuff, ie. compare count of $tt_ids and $old_tt_ids
}

wp_set_object_terms($id, array($migrate_case), 'pa_case');

remove_filter( 'set_object_terms', 'checkNewTerm', 10, 6 );
```